# Is there an UIAccessibility event when user taps item again?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, accessibility, voiceover

VoiceOver calls

```
- (void)accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused {
    // user activates the item first time
}

- (void)accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus {
    // user activates different item
}
```

but I need to know, when user taps item **again**.

When user taps UIPickerView for example it says out loud "5 minutes. picker item. adjustable". When user taps again, it repeats this.

VoiceOver doesnt call DidBecomeFocused method when it was already activated. How can I figure out when user taps again?

Comment: I don't know, from what you describe it seems these messages are sent only when the focused element actually changes (which is not the case when the user taps the item). However if you don't mind, it would interest me why do you want to know when the VoiceOver focus (cursor) reaches your element?

Comment: Because of a custom control that is a UITableView to select a value. Similar like a picker view.